# Creating a table header(th) and body(td) from json in angular app

Tags: json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular app where i am trying to create a table from a json. My json is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "campus_id": "321", 
        "name": "0"
    }, 
    {
        "campus_id": "231", 
        "name": "1"
    }, 
    {
        "campus_id": "123", 
        "name": "2"
    }
]
```

Generally we will create a table in the html as follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Campus id
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>    
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td >
            {{item.campus_id}}
        </td>
        <td >
            {{item.name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do i create even the headers from the json instead of defining them ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

I would add the column headers within the json result like so

```
columnDefs: [
     {field: 'campus_id', displayName: 'Campus ID'},
     {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}],

data:
[
    {
        "campus_id": "57911000", 
        "name": "0"
    }, 
    {
        "campus_id": "57911001", 
        "name": "HIGHLAND PARK HIGH SCHOOL"
    }, 
    {
        "campus_id": "57911007", 
        "name": "P A S S Learning Center School"
    }
]
```

otherwise you could use the key, value pairing  ng-repeat="(key,value) in items" with a filter to return 1 row and then use {{key}}